# add values depending on a condition sql-server

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a table like this:

```
create table example(
id char(1),
color varchar,
col_binary binary);
```

I already have a stored procedure and I want through the stored procedure that will return me a color for example "blue" then the `col_binary` column  takes values ​​1, and with another color such as "red" `col_binary` takes value 0.
I guess I need a trigger.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very difficult to understand, can you improve the English please? Also, are you saying when you INSERT, you want `col_binary` to become a certain value?

Comment: Why not have a separate table that stores the binary value for each colour, then you can join to this to get your binary column, alternatively add a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - e.g. `ALTER TABLE example ADD col_binary AS CASE Color WHEN 'Blue' THEN 1 WHEN 'Red' THEN 0 END;`

Comment: Please remember that when declaring `color varchar` the length of the column is `1`! You should always specify the length of the `varchar(10)` to prevent truncation

Comment: If there is no intention to change col_binary independent from color, normalizing would be a better way. `create table example(
id char(1),
color varchar(20)
);

create table Color2binary(
color varchar(20),
col_binary binary);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve it by adding a trigger like this

```
Create Trigger [Add_LTD] on Example
After Insert As
BEGIN
Update Example set Example.[col_binary]=case when Example.[Color]='Red' then 1 else 0 END from Inserted 
where Example.id=Inserted.id
END;
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/76fd5/1)